# Find physical location of USB port?

Tags: usb

I recently discovered that my computer has an USB3 entry:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But pysically, I only have USB2 entries, so I would like to find wich one is and replace it with an USB3.

I'm having some problems to find the physical location of `Bus 002`, how could I do this?

I first tried by plugging an usb over each port one by one and then checking the log `lsusb -v`,I thought that the `bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused` value should change, but it didn't.

Then I realized that my mouse, appears listed with `lsusb`, so I plugged it over the three different entries and looked to the `lsusb` log.

1rst usb entry:
`Bus 001 Device 009: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver`

2nd usb entry:
`Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver`

3rd usb entry:
`Bus 003 Device 014: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver`

I couln't find a connection to the `bus 002`. Is there any command that could help me figuring this out?  Thanks!

Comment: Your motherboard might have internal USB3 ports (on a desktop computer)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I actually have a laptop but I do think so. Do my test proved that actually my two first entries uses the same bus? Kinda weird that the manufacturer did this and left alone the USB3

Comment: try testing your ports by plugging in a USB3.0 device (your mouse is very unlikely to be USB 3.0).  It's not uncommon to have dual-mode USB ports that can be used as either USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 or both.  So the USB3.0 ports may be physically the same  as the USB 2.0 ports, and the kernel has loaded both 2.0 and 3.0 drivers for them.

Comment: I just wanted to add that it is kinda weird, but a friend lend me a hard drive that turns a led in blue when it is plugged over an USB3, and the weird thing is that it turns blue over the first two usb entries, the ones that should be using USB2 as the command `lsusb` indicates it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see if they are ports connected to the hub 3.0  using the command

```
lsusb -t
```

You can also check the status of the ports may be present with the command

```
lsusb -v -s 002
```

may be that the USB 3.0 hub has not been connected (perhaps because it is intended for a higher model) or to serve for internal devices.